# How can I set an icon on a tag?

Tags: support, tags, sponsored-tags

I don't know if the term is correct - but how are these icons set on some tags?
Do I need a special privileges to do that?

And what about the IP permissions - can I for instance set a picture from Wikipedia?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

The icons are *sponsorships*; you need to contact the Stack Exchange sales team to sponsor a tag; it is one of the ways Stack Exchange makes money from the site. The icon is provided by the sponsor of the tag.

The [google-app-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine) tag is sponsored by Google, for example; they provided the icon and the sponsor's message at the top of the tag page:

[image]

See the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/advertising) for more information or click on the *advertisement info* link in the footer of the site.

The feature is not otherwise generally available; not for open source projects, nor can you use reputation to sponsor a tag.

Comment: Maybe not with reputation - but if one managed to hold onto some unicoins! ;-)

Comment: I understand this is to make money, but shouldn't there be some way OSS projects could get an icon, short of paying for it?

Comment: Open Source projects can make use of the [community-voted adverts](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/) instead. See the [meta-tag:community-ads] tag.

Comment: How would one go about sponsoring a tag? Could I, for example, sponsor the python tag? Who must I throw the money at who how much of it must I throw? Or would I need to somehow prove that the tag belonged to me (how?)

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: contact advertising sales; you need to have a significant connection to the tag however; unless you are the Python Software Foundation, expect requests for sponsoring that tag to be turned down.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: see [Should tags that represent concepts be sponsorable?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104757) for the current policies. You need to be owner of the trademark.