# Should tag wikis have images?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I have been making various tag wiki edits, and came across this one made in July: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3608751/10, which removed an image on the tag wiki page for Solr added a few weeks earlier.

I have been unable to find any documentation on what should go into wiki pages, so I thought I'd ask: why was the image removed, and is there a general policy for images in wikis? If there is not currently a policy, do we want to have images in wikis in future?

Comment: Since it was a mod who removed that, and left a pretty clear comment why, I'd suppose it's not wanted to have logos in tag wikis.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't see this "pretty clear comment why". All it says is "don't do that".

Comment: no need to put logo images in tag wiki. if it's an informative image of some type, maybe not a problem

Comment: I don't think a logo in a tag wiki is helpful; it doesn't tell you anything about how the tag should be used. That logo took up a large chunk of screen estate.

Comment: img tags are allowed in the tag wiki section so nothing will stop someone from putting an image there. The problem I see is that logos are protected by a trademark law and the images could be copyrighted. They will also be hosted externally (unless you re-upload them to imgur using the editor) and may break. I also kinda found a use case for an image http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css-float/info . Some tag benefit from a visual representation but I can't find that many and in most cases it adds very little detail.. Oh and it was also added by animuson♦ who removed the logo for that tag

Comment: @Spokey: I am by no means a lawyer, but wouldn't that fall under fair use?

Comment: @linuxios yes and no depending on the text that comes with it

Comment: MSE dupe (with official answer): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130623/company-logos-on-tag-wikis-are-they-allowed

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "left a pretty clear comment why" Where do you see that?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Those are paid-for sponserships. The company that owns the product the tag is for, such as Google, pays to have their icon there. See [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251363/how-can-i-set-an-icon-on-a-tag).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my opinion it is an eye sore. The logo adds nothing useful to the wiki and is quite distracting. I've taken a look at the [solr website](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and at the bottom it says:

> Apache and the Apache feather logo are trademarks of The Apache
>   Software Foundation. Apache Lucene, Apache Solr and their respective
>   logos are trademarks of the Apache Software Foundation. Please see the
>   [Apache Trademark Policy](https://www.apache.org/foundation/marks/)
>   for more information.

Much like [Stackoverflow's Trademark Guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance), Apache's [Trademark Policy](https://www.apache.org/foundation/marks/) goes into some legalese about how you can use their logo. I suppose if one really cared about inserting a logo into the wiki, you could examine the policy and ensure usage of the logo doesn't violate it, but that seems to require a disproportionate amount of care to carelessly adding a logo to the wiki. For example, under **What is nominative use?** it says:

> Anyone can use ASF trademarks if that use of the trademark is
>   nominative. The "nominative use" (or "nominative fair use") defense to
>   trademark infringement is a legal doctrine that authorizes everyone
>   (even commercial companies) to use another person's trademark as long
>   as three requirements are met:
>
> [...]
>
> 3. The organization using the mark must do nothing that would, in conjunction with the mark, suggest sponsorship or endorsement by the
>      trademark holder.

Then under **What is the "confusing similarity" or "likelihood of confusion" test?**

> To avoid infringing ASF's marks, you should verify that your use of
>   our marks is nominative and that you are not likely to confuse
>   software consumers that your software is the same as ASF's software or
>   is endorsed by ASF. This policy is already summarized in section 6 of
>   the Apache License , and so it is a condition for your use of Apache
>   software:
>
> ```
> This License does not grant permission to use the trade names,
> trademarks, service marks, or product names of the Licensor, except as
> required for reasonable and customary use in describing the origin of
> the Work and reproducing the content of the NOTICE file.
> ```

To me, that seems like a lot of stuff that would clutter up the wiki which would otherwise contain a succinct summary of the tag in question.