# Is there a reason that pretty much only Google-related tags show a pretty icon?

Tags: discussion, tags, sponsored-tags

I see that a lot of tags have a nice little icon presented next to the name. It doesn't show here, but if you visit the pages for [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and [paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal) you'll see what I'm talking about.
Is it just me or do the Google-related tags seem to have been given more love than all the others with regard to the icon?  To be fair, there are a lot of non-Google tags that have an icon, but very, very few Microsoft- or Apple-related tags are fancied up.  Is there a reason for this?

Comment: The obvious conclusion is that Google has [deeper pockets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251363/how-can-i-set-an-icon-on-a-tag).

Comment: Ah.  I didn't know you had to _pay_ to put an icon on the tag!  That would explain the unevenness with the tag icons.

Comment: The duplicate question tells you *why* the Google-related tags have an icon; the other part of the question is primarily opinion-based.