# Exposure of business-oriented products

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-business

I'm just now learning about most of Stack Overflow's business-oriented products.  I knew about Jobs, but the rest haven't really been mentioned anywhere that I frequent.  I'd have liked to have known about them sooner; they're products in which I'm legitimately interested, and they're more relevant to me than most ads that might otherwise appear on the site, including job ads.

The [Stack Overflow Business site](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/) seems to list most of the relevant products, but I'd never visited it before.  The website isn't clear about what the products are; when I see "Ads", I think lame, old, boring ads that half the visitors are probably blocking.  There's nothing to indicate that you can actually get [this sort of advertising](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251363/how-can-i-set-an-icon-on-a-tag), which I find a lot more interesting.

This raises the question: how are companies expected to discover these products?  They're unique, they're innovative, but they're not advertised anywhere.  Stack Overflow is a vital resource for every development team; we all stand to gain from Stack Overflow bringing in more revenue.  When they don't make enough money, [unfortunate compromises have to be made](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation/).  I'd like to think it's possible to raise awareness of these products passively without annoying community members.  How could this be done?  Or is it already being done, and I'm just blind?

Just to demonstrate how little exposure some of these products receive, I paged through all Meta tags until I hit tags with only three associations and couldn't find anything covering the entirety of Stack Overflow Business.  Most product-specific tags had single-digit association numbers.  Examples:

- [jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jobs) + [careers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/careers) = 1060; only product to receive a lot of publicity
- [advertising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advertising) = 134; mostly complaints and bug reports
- [sponsored-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sponsored-tags) = 21
- [stackoverflow-talent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-talent) = 9
- [trends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trends) = 4
- [so-enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/so-enterprise) = 2
- [insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/insights) = 1
- [channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/channels) = 1

Comment: I'm pretty sure they market this stuff through other channels. Many (most?) developers are arguably not *exactly* in the business target audience (although many probably influence related decisions), and many (most?) devs here would be annoyed if business content was pushed to them too aggressively.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I attend conferences, get enterprise-oriented ads through ad networks, etc., but I've never seen anything from SO.  If there were a simple "Enterprise" link in the menu on the homepage, I would've clicked it.

Comment: Something like that (maybe not an entire menu item, but a really well visible link) is a fair idea I suppose.