# Should tag icons have logos from competitors?

Tags: bug, status-completed, sponsored-tags

I recently noticed that the Power BI tag ([powerbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi)) has the Tableau logo on it ([tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau)). This was jarring, but I'm not sure how big a deal it is. [Power BI is a Microsoft product](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/).

Based on [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251363/how-can-i-set-an-icon-on-a-tag) it appears that these are sponsored.

Power BI Tag, with Tableau logo: [image: power bi tag logo]

And here's the Tableau logo, from [Tableau's website](https://www.tableau.com/): [image: tableau logo]

Comment: That's a bit creepy, IMO. I hope it's a mistake.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up. I work on the Ad Ops team and this was an incorrect implementation. The sponsorship icon should not appear on the powerbi tag. We're correcting this today.